# How can I add multiple icons to an individual TreeView item?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, treeview

I am trying to display multiple icons to the Treeview item but it is not displaying all the icons, it displays only one.
I am using the following code:

```
CImageList m_imageState;
m_cTree.m_imageState.Create(16, 16, ILC_MASK, 0, 4);
m_cTree.m_imageState.Add(&bm, RGB(255,255,0));
m_cTree.m_imageState.Add(&bm2, RGB(255,0,255));
m_cTree.m_imageState.Add(&bm, RGB(255,255,0));
m_cTree.m_imageState.Add(&bm1, RGB(0,255,255));
m_cTree.SetImageList( &(m_cTree.m_imageState), TVSIL_NORMAL );
```

But when I see Treeview, item displays only one icon.
Is it possible to display multiple icons with Treeview item?

Please suggest how can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, only one icon will be displayed per item in a `TreeView` control. This is by design, a hard limitation of the native control that the MFC library wraps.

The only way you're going to be able to display multiple icons per item is [owner drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761817.aspx). It's a pretty difficult task for a `TreeView` control, not nearly as easy as owner drawing a button or a label control. Make sure that you really this need this functionality, and consider whether there's a better way of displaying the relevant information to your users.

Alternatively, you could create custom bitmaps that combine multiple images next to one another, and add those to your `ImageList`. The resulting images will be wider than they are tall, but the control doesn't care: it will display whatever size images you specify, as long as all the images in the image list have the same dimensions. This is definitely a hack, but it might work, depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...
In my case bitmaps are different different icons so i dont think i can combine multiple images next to one another. So i think i need to drop the plan to display multiple images.

Comment: @Nikhil: Well, you can draw the individual icons into a bitmap in memory, then load that bitmap into the `ImageList`. That would work fine if you didn't need to change the icons displayed very often. For example, you could just draw 3 16x16 icons next to one another in a new memory bitmap when your application first loads, creating a 48x16 bitmap, then assign that bitmap to the `ImageList`. But yeah, if that doesn't work for you, I'd definitely give up. I can't imagine a situation where it'd be worth it to owner draw a TreeView just to get multiple icons.

Comment: My Treeview can contains items in thousands and the Icons could be different for each Treeview item.So in this scenario i feel that the drawing image in new memory bitmap would be a costly operation??